# plt.imsave() saved grayscale image as RGBA. Applying the same transformation using cv2 gives a different image

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

```
plt.imsave(f"{save_path}/img.png", spectrogram[0]) # Saves as 4 channel (RGBA I assume)
spectrogram1 = torchvision.io.read_image(f"{save_path}/img.png", io.ImageReadMode.GRAY)[0].float()
spectrogram1 = torch.stack([spectrogram1, spectrogram1])
```

spectrogram is a two channel image (shape=(2,X)) with values ranging from -80 to +50. The read file spectrogram1 ranges from 0 to 255 but looks the same when plotted.

```
spectrogram2 = cv2.cvtColor(spectrogram[0], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
spectrogram2 = cv2.cvtColor(spectrogram2, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
spectrogram2 = torch.stack([spectrogram2, spectrogram2])
```

spectrogram2 has the same range as spectrogram1 and also looks very similar. But somehow is very different as the classification model which is trained on images like spectrogram1 gives random output on images like spectrogram2.

Why are spectrograms 1 and 2 different? Also, how can I perform the exact same transformation as spectrogram1 during inference, without saving the file which adds a lot of IO overhead.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a proper [mcve] - even if it is just dummy (synthetic) data of a gradient image in the correct range and dtype. Also make sure it is complete and runnable with all `import` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use `pyplot.imsave` to store gray-scale images. See [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html):

> If you want to save a single channel image as gray scale please use an image I/O library (such as pillow, tifffile, or imageio) directly.

`pyplot.imsave` first min-max stretches the image, then applies the viridis color map. These steps can be reproduced by appropriate function calls in Matplotlib without saving to file. It would be something like this:

```py
cm = matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap() # default color map, viridis
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
rgb = cm(norm(spectrogram[0]))
```

When you read the PNG image back as a gray-scale image, the viridis color map colors are transformed to gray-scale in some way not specified by the documentation, you’d have to read the source code to learn what conversion is applied. You could try using OpenCV with `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY`, see if it matches. But a better bet is looking for the color convention function in `torchvision`.